# Cannot dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, class, casting, abstract-class

I am having the following error when trying to compile my code.

> ERROR! ..\myCode\CPOI.cpp:68:41: error: cannot dynamic_cast
>   'screenType' (of type 'struct CScreen*') to type 'struct CGUIScreen*'
>   (target is not pointer or reference to complete type)

This is my code:

Base class:

```
#include "CRoute.h"

enum screen_t{CRTScreen,GUIScreen};

class CScreen
{
    protected:    
        CRoute* m_pRoute;

    public:    
        virtual ~CScreen();
        virtual void connecToRoute(CRoute* route) = 0;
        virtual void drawRoute() = 0;
        virtual screen_t getScreenType() = 0;
};
```

Derived class:

```
#include "CScreen.h"

class CGUIScreen : public CScreen
{
    public:
        void drawRoute();
        screen_t getScreenType();
        void connecToRoute(CRoute* route);
};
```

And the error:

```
void CPOI::print(int format, CScreen* screenType)
{
    if(dynamic_cast<CGUIScreen*>(screenType)) 
    {
        cout << "printing POI GUI " << endl;
    }   
}
```

Why is it happening?

Comment: make virtual methods also in derived class and try again. You must override all pure virtual functions.

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Nothing here looks wrong. Are you sure you included the derived class definition from where you're doing the cast?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't shown enough code, so it is only possible to guess.

The error is probably because, when compiling the offending statement,  the compiler only has visibility of forward declarations of `CGUIScreen` (and possibly also `CScreen`).   The solution would be to `#include` the header file that defines `CGUIScreen` class, so the compiler has visibility of the complete class definitions for the `dynamic_cast`.

Or, to put it another way, a forward declaration like `class CGUIScreen;` is not sufficient for an expression like `dynamic_cast<CGUIScreen*>(screenType)`.    The complete class definition is needed.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete code. You are right, thank you.